# Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target with Scala

Tags: scala

I practice Scala by solving algo questions and stuck on this problem from leetcode:

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such
>   that they add up to a specific target. You may assume that each input
>   would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element
>   twice.

```
Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].
```

I came up with the following code

```
def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
    val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[Int, Int]
    nums.zipWithIndex.foreach{ case(num, idx) => 
        map.get(idx) match {
            case Some(r) => return Array(r, idx)
            case None => map += (idx -> (target-num))
       }
    }
    Array(-1, -1)
}
```

It seems that the I'm adding values to `map` in a wrong way, as for every input I get an Array(-1,-1) as a result.

The expected soultion.

```
def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
    var map = Map.empty[Int, Int]
    for ((v, i) <- nums.zipWithIndex) {
       map.get(v) match {
           case Some(r) => return Array(r, i)
           case None => map ++= Map((target - v) -> i)
       }
    }
    Array(-1, -1)
}
```

Can you point on my mistake and explain how to update hashMap properly? While updating the elements with mutable Map I was referencing this [post](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-add-update-remove-mutable-map-elements-scala-cookbook/).

Comment: As a note: there is no reason for you to use mutability in this example at all. And no reason to use `return` as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the second solution you have a map of value to index, which is correct. But in the first one you have the opposite: a map from index to value, which is wrong. So you have to reverse the entries you add to the `Map`:

```
def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
  val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[Int, Int]
  nums.zipWithIndex.foreach{ case(num, idx) =>
    map.get(num) match {                     // Changed: retrieving the index of the value 
      case Some(r) => return Array(r, idx)
      case None => map += ((target-num) -> idx)  // Changed: adding (value -> index) pairs
    }
  }
  Array(-1, -1)
}
```

---

For the record, if you want to avoid using mutability and `return`, the simplest way to do it would be to precompute the `Map` in one pass, and then do the second pass to find both indexes:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
  val indexByValue = HashMap(nums.zipWithIndex: _*)
  val result = nums.indices.collectFirst(Function.unlift { i =>
    indexByValue.get(target - nums(i)).filter(_ != i).map(Array(i, _))
  })
  result.getOrElse(Array(-1, -1))
}
```

This is still slower than the mutable version, because it does two passes over `nums` and eagerly builds the whole `Map`, while the original mutable code only does a single pass and builds the `Map` lazily. To compute the `Map` lazily in a single pass in a functional way you can use `scanLeft` over an iterator or some lazy collection:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
  nums.indices.iterator
    .scanLeft(HashMap.empty[Int, Int]) { (map, i) =>
      map + (nums(i) -> i)
    }
    .zipWithIndex
    .collectFirst(Function.unlift { case (indexByValue, i) =>
      indexByValue.get(target - nums(i)).filter(_ != i).map(Array(i, _))
    })
    .getOrElse(Array(-1, -1))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate what you would do on an imperative language, a nested for.
*(note: I changed the signature a bit to be more idiomatic, you can just call this function on the original one, adapting the inputs and outputs)*

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq // Immutable array, only exists on 2.13

def twoSum(nums: ArraySeq[Int], target: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] =
  Iterator
    .range(start = 0, end = nums.length)
    .map { i =>
      Iterator
        .range(start = (i + 1), end = nums.length)
        .collectFirst {
          case j if ((nums(i) + nums(j)) == target) =>
            (i, j)
        }
    } collectFirst {
      case Some(tuple) => tuple
    }
```

Which you can use like:

```
twoSum(ArraySeq(1, 3, 5, 2, 0, 4), target = 8)
// res: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,2))

twoSum(ArraySeq(1, 3, 5, 2, 0, 4), target = 10)
// res: Option[(Int, Int)] = None
```